# Show certain DIVs with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

In a Blog you can determine a tag for each post e.g. Video, Photo, Quote etc... If I created a div class for each tag e.g.

```
<div class="Video"></div>
<div class="Photo"></div>
<div class="Quote"></div>
```

How can I create a onclick link so when I click it only shows div's called Video and hides all other div's?

Comment: Did my solution work ??  Or do you want it in Javascript without Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/vpqrX/1/)

Using Jquery....

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.filter').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filter = $(this).html();
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('.'+filter).show();
    });
});
```

Then in your HTML

```
<a class="filter">Video</a>
<a class="filter">Photo</a>
```

And your divs....

```
<div class="boxes Video">Blahblah</div>
<div class="boxes Photo">Blahblah</div>
```

Or you can do it using data attributes, to keep your HTML more readable...but this works too

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/vpqrX/1/)

Comment: Thats how I tryed the first time but just like your example when I try to show All of them again if still hides the last clicked filter..

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. And it would be much better if you give all your "tag" [`div`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/div.html#div)s a [`class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) like, for example, `tag` and separated with a space it's specific type.

For example `class="tag audio"`. But this should work for now:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var tags = ['Video', 'Photo', 'Quote'], tag = $(this).attr('class');

    if ($.inArray(tag, tags)) {
        $('.' + tag).show();
        $('div').not('.' + tag).hide();
    }
});
```